# SFTP in jdk1.4?

Tags: java

I am developing an application using java and SFTP. I am using SFTP in jdk1.6 but it consumed lot of machine memory. Is it possible to use SFTP in jdk1.4 ?

Comment: Why do you think that going to an even more unsupported version of Java will reduce your memory footprint?

Comment: This question is off topic on SO.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Consider moving it to: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use SFTP in jdk1.4

Yes it is possible.  At least in some cases.  Whether it requires changes to your application will depend on *how* you have implemented SFTP; i.e. what libraries you have used.

However:

1. It is doubtful (IMO) that switching to Java 1.4.x will make a significant difference to memory usage.
2. If you have a problem with memory usage, it is likely that the real culprit / cause of the problem is your application rather than the SFTP library that you are using.

The other problem with going back to an old version of Java is that it may introduce compatibility issues at the SSL / TLS level.  There have been changes to the protocols (new versions) and some of the old versions have been deprecated.  If you try to talk to an SFTP server that won't accept an old version (for security reasons) and your client side only supports old versions ('cos the JVM is old), then then connection negotiation may fail.

(You may be able to workaround that with 3rd-party libraries ... )

---

But my recommendation would be to look at *why* your application's memory usage is too large.  Don't just assume it is SFTP's fault.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response.

I'm trying to recompile my application to 1.4 because I've notice that the memory size it used dramatically reduced when running using 1.4. I'm  using this command to check the memory size:

ps -eo size,pid,user,command --sort -size

The original developer of this application claimed that he can't run the application with SFTP using 1.4 (though it compiles successfully), but I need it to be in 1.4. :(

Comment: *"I've notice that the memory size it used dramatically reduced when running using 1.4"* - That's probably just because you are using the default heap sizes.  Read up on the "-xmx" and "-xms" JVM options.

Comment: *"The original developer of this application claimed that he can't run the application with SFTP using 1.4"* - He is probably correct ... for the reasons above, or maybe because older JVMs don't understand SFTP natively.  (It depends on how the application uses SFTP, as I said in my answer.  If you don't understand that, you probably ought to just take the developer's word for it!!)

Answer (score 0):

With [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/), you can get SFTP running with versions as low as 1.2.2, after adding Bouncycastle library, or since 1.4.0 if without any changes.

Difficult to say without trying if it would use much less resources. I would recommend to give a try for Java 1.8 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try Apache commons [VFS](http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/vfs/binaries/) library, 1.0 has support for JDK 1.4